# Percona MyRocks storage engine and replication

Tags: mysql, percona, rocksdb

Can anyone advise me if we choose Percona MyRocks storage engine on the slave and replicating off Galera Cluster running Innodb engine. Would such replication work and if so what are the chances of it breaking on schema changes done on Galera cluster via Pt-schema-change.

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB is the only supported storage engine for Galera/PXC replication.

Re-reading your question, it seems you want to use MyRocks on a slave in a 'traditional' async replication scenario, not as part of a cluster. This *should* work fine as long as that slave does not participate in the Galera cluster. MyRocks only really works well with ROW format, so no STMT/MIX. Any replicated DDL that might alter the engine will cause the slave table alteration to the target engine.

Comment: I want to use a async slave off Galera cluster. Perhaps you are right if we are creating a new table or altering a table via PT-OSC it may be replicated over to the slave breaking replication on the slave running with MyRocks db engine